# C++ - How to get points of rotating cylinder?

Tags: c++, 3d, curve

I need the points of a "rotating cylinder". I've got some lines of a curve and looking for an implementation to calculate 16 points arount them to get a cycle. My implemenation looks like:

```
QPointF MappingModel::calcThicknessYarns(float fCurrentX, float fCurrentY, int iCurrentCounter)
{
QPointF nextPoint;

int iAmountOfThicknessYarns = 16;
float fSingleAngle = 360.0 / iAmountOfThicknessYarns;

float fCurrentAngle = fSingleAngle * iCurrentCounter;

nextPoint = getXY(fCurrentAngle, 1.0, 1.0, fCurrentX, fCurrentY);

return nextPoint; 
}
```

and

```
QPointF MappingModel::getXY(float angle, float width, float height, float xOffset, float yOffset)       
{
QPointF xy;

float FI = angle*PIdev;
xy.setX((width * qCos(FI)) + xOffset) ;
xy.setY((height * qSin(FI)) - yOffset);

return xy;
}
```

My looks like this:

http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3741/e8bafwni_jpg.htm
http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3741/tkykay7w_jpg.htm

As you can see, the the vertical cylinder works fine, but the curve is false

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

It shouldn't be difficult to adapt `Vertex` to `QPointF`.

```
typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
} Vertex;

/**
 * @param radius Radius of circle
 * @param angle Degrees
 * @return The offset of vertex from the center of circle given radius and angle
 */
Vertex getVerticeOffset(double radius, double angle) {
    double yOffset = -radius*cos((90 - angle)*M_PI/180);  // convert to radians
    return Vertex({(angle >= 90 && angle < 270 ? -1 : 1) * sqrt(pow(radius, 2) - pow(yOffset, 2)), yOffset});
}
```